# Receive the value of Griffin Technology USB Powermate programmatically. (mac catalina / Windows 10)

Tags: macos, windows-10, usb

I have purchased a [Griffin Technology USB Powermate](https://www.amazon.co.jp/Griffin-Technology-NA16029-PowerMate-%E3%80%90%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E3%81%AAUSB%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%83%A1%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%80%91/dp/B003VWU2WA) and want to use this to map to values on the program. Specifically, I would like to be able to receive values in a format similar to OSC, in max/MSP, C++, Node.js, or Python. I use a Mac Catalina for development. (Windows 10 is also available)

Please let me know if you have any insights. Thank you for your time.

---

[Griffin Technology USB Powermate](https://www.amazon.co.jp/Griffin-Technology-NA16029-PowerMate-%E3%80%90%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E3%81%AAUSB%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%83%A1%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%80%91/dp/B003VWU2WA)を購入し、これをプログラムの外部USBコントローラーとして使用したいと思っています。Driver対応などについてもアップデートがされていないみたいでどのように使用すれば良いか分からない状態です。OSCと同じようなフォーマットで値をmax/MSPかC++、Node.js、Pythonのどれかに送ることができたら嬉しいです。現在私はMac Catalinaを使って開発をおこなっています。(Windows 10も可)

何か知見などありましたらご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 当サイトでは主に日本語でのやり取りを想定していますので、あなたが日本語で読み書きできるのであれば英文の併記は不要です。(英語で質問したい場合には、個別に [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) に投稿してください。)

Comment: 多分最初期のレビュー。[こりゃヤケにカッコいい!! 「PowerMate」](https://k-tai.watch.impress.co.jp/cda/article/stapa/8901.html), 割と最近の紹介とレビュー。[USBボリュームダイヤル！Griffin Technology NA16029 PowerMateレビュー](http://laineema.gger.jp/archives/5168638.html), [つまみ型コントローラー「PowerMate」でDAWのつまみをグリグリしたかったので買ってみた。](https://kohrogi.com/?p=6600), 他に自身で紹介されているAmazonのカスタマレビューをたどるとパラパラと情報があるようです。類似品だと[Surface Dial](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/p/surface-dial/925r551sktgn?activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab), [List of Microsoft Surface accessories - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Surface_accessories) でしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

該当の製品はかなり古いもののようで (2015年～16年頃)、対応 OS も Windows XP や Vista 止まりで
[公式サイト](https://griffintechnology.com/) 上では検索しても見つからず、既にラインナップやサポートから外れているようです。

そもそも想定しているような開発者向けの利用方法がサポートされているのかをまずは確認すべきではないでしょうか？ (恐らくは製品のユーティリティ経由での利用しか対応していないような気がします)